# Intake Platform that Integrates Well With Clio

Tags: crm, legal

I work for a law firm that uses Clio (Manage) heavily as our CRM. However, we have a policy that only current or previous clients may be on Clio, meaning leads/prospective clients may not be on there. We currently use Monday.com to track our prospective clients, but it is inefficient in my opinion. I would appreciate suggestions for intake platforms that integrate directly with Clio. I don't necessarily want suggestions for CRMs to replace Clio, but I won't forbid them.

**Note:** We have tried Clio Grow, but found that it oddly doesn't integrate very well with Clio Manage.